# How to manage a winforms application installed in many PCs connected to a single sql database?

Tags: refactoring, winforms

I have a winforms application that connects to a single sql server 2012 database and is executed in many PCs of a company.

I'm having several problems with some transactions inside the application, deadlocks and timeouts so the refactor idea comes to my head.

Actually the app is using DbConnection object (the app starts with Framework 2.0 and recently was updated to Framework 3.5 but the data access layer was not changed) to perform the sql calls to the database and in the Program.cs the connection is opened and until the user doesn't close the app the connection maintains opened.

What are my options to refactor this app?

- Entity Framework? => With this I must to say that the SQL database
  has not Foreign Keys
- Refactor the Data Access Layer to use a more efficient connection? Maybe using TransactionScope?
- Is the always connected app efficient?

Comment: You are walking down a well-tread path - your app's usage has grown (great!) and now it needs to properly scale. You will probably want to bring in some expertise - someone with solid experience in scaling-out distributed systems. This effort is akin to replacing a 5-node wifi network with a 1000-node sub-netted LAN.

Comment: Define "many PCs" - 20, 200, 2000? And notice that "refactoring" means "not changing the behaviour of the code" - that is not what you want.

Comment: Many PCs are like less than 50. That's what i want it to say about re-factoring... i do not pretend to change the behavior of the code.

Comment: What @DocBrown is saying is that you *do* want to change the behaviour of the code. If you don't change the behaviour of the code, you will not resolve your timeout and deadlock problems. Refactoring wouldn't solve those problems, you need to actually change the way the code behaves and interacts with the DB to resolve them. For starters, do you use `(NOLOCK)` throughout your reads where the accuracy of the data can be outdated by a few seconds?

Comment: @JimmyHoffa got me 100% right. The correct term for this is not refactoring, but bugfixing, since deadlocks, timeouts, and wrong transactions are kind of bugs. And the primary strategy for bugfixing should be always **root cause analysis**. Your question sounds like you want to avoid that step - trying some heavy changes, wishfully thinking this might help, because searching for the root cause is too tedious. Sorry, but this has a IMHO a high chance of bringing you not a bit further.

Comment: The tactics which will typically help is extensive logging, finding the transactions which cause your problems, rethink your locking strategies *in the specific cases*, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Migrating to a different technology will not necessarily prevent deadlocks and timeouts and other "application-level" problems. You'll just be rearranging the deckchairs.

There are many cases where this client-server model works, it is efficient generally - as long as your clients don;t do things like read a big query and keep the lock on the DB resultset (as some "edit results" controls can do).

The trick is to read what you need, work with it and update what you changed afterwards, allowing others to play nicely with the same DB resource. If you moved to, say a 3-tier architecture where the DB connection is held by a central service, then you'll have to adopt this approach anyway.

Apart from that, I can't really help- it depends on your program its usage and the bad things it does. A 3-tier approach is a good thing though, and if you design it so it is not tied to a specific winforms client, you'll be able to reuse the central server with future clients (eg a web one)

Comment: My application already have a 3-tier architecture and that's the best thing because i can modify my Data Access Layer with the different options. I think i will start using TransactionScope and refactor my code.